# Why HTTP Requset abort or i can't get the response?

Tags: php, javascript, http, xmlhttprequest, firebug

i'm trying to send an HTTP request to php file and get the users names so in while loop I send a request every loop but what happen that the request get aborted this happen in the Firebug.

```
function getBody(){
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
            http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }else{
            http = new ActiveXObject(microsoft.XMLHTTP);
        }
        limit =getC();
        i=1;
        while(i <= 50){
            http.onreadystatechange = function(){       
                    if(http.readyState == 4){
                        getPosts(http.responseText , i);
                    }
            }
            http.open("get","../php/php.php?q=getBody&id=comment"+i);       
            http.send();
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can use `http.open("GET","...",false);` to make the request synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

check in firebug where is the destination in http.open

### "../php/php.php?q=getBody&id=comment"+i

i think this parameter needs to be modified, it happend alot with me
and also sometimes it works in localhost but not online and vice versa